# How to disable UI rotation in iOS, but rotate in VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, objective-c, voiceover

I am attempting to replicate the experience of the iOS camera where, upon rotation, the UI itself does not rotate, but the individual elements do. Visually I was able to replicate the effect perfectly by setting the following in my view controller:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Additionally, I listen to the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` and rotate the views using `CGAffineTransform` when the event is triggered. Again, this works perfectly visually. However, the rotation fails to take effect in VoiceOver. When I rotate to landscape, I'd expect that the left and right swipe would still let me navigate across elements. However, I have to do up and down swipes instead. What is another way to accomplish this effect that would work for sighted and VoiceOver users?

Comment: Stupid, but honest question... does the behavior work for both sighted and VoiceOver users in the Camera app? Your question didn't specifically state that it does.

Comment: Yes, it does work as expected for the iOS Camera app.

Comment: Ok. I took a chance it would fail my "show me an example" test. :-) I have no experience with VoiceOver or how Camera uses it. But the only thing that comes to mind is something "invisible" - probably a UIView since you can't attach gestures easily to a CALayer. This invisible view also does not rotate, but since it's the target for the gesture and is also top-most in the view hierarchy, the left/right sticks when rotated. Good luck figuring this out.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but which exactly UIView(s) you rotate? The trick that I think might work is to find some `UIView` that is close to the hierarchy root, rotate it according to the device orientation change and additionally rotate back the camera preview `UIView`. There is a chance that after such trick Voice Over gesture recognizer will change orientation as well.

Comment: I tried that approach already, in both a device orientation observer as well as in viewWillTransition. It did not help.

Comment: Have you tried an approach where the controller actually allows the interface orientation change, but you offset the rotation of your view using a transform (and then rotate the sub views as you do right now)?

Comment: This may be a radical approach but `UIWindow` won't react to device orientation changes and it can have subviews too. The orientation responsive UI would remain being managed by a view controller.

Comment: @LeoNatan Yeah, I tried that approach. Did not work. Apparently that only works if AutoLayout is not being used.

Comment: @Kamil.S Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Both UIWindow and UIViewController have addSubview: method. Assuming super simplistic POC approach: add views that are supposed be to orientation-wise static directly to UIWindow and those reacting to orientation to VC. Set the VC as the root vc of the UIWindow. If your frames overlap you will have to manage it somehow to be able to see those added directly to UIWindow. For POC purposes I'd devote part of the screen to UIWindow and part to VC to see if the outcome UI subviews behaviour leads in the right direction.In the VC keep your already working code for handling device orientation change.

Comment: Could you maybe post a link to a minimal project showing the behaviour?

Comment: I did some testing and relying on UIWindow will no longer work as it did till iOS7. Hence what I recommend is making the vc for portrait orientation only, detect the actual orientation of the device and then apply rotation to the layers for views which should be responsive to orientation.

Comment: @Kamil.S That is precisely what I've already done. The trouble I am facing is to get it work correctly on VoiceOver.

Comment: I would expect the vc to actually disallow rotating, so autorotate should return NO. This (in theory) should restrict VoiceOver reacting to the orientation change.

Comment: @Kamil.S I want VoiceOver to react to the orientation change, just like in the Camera app. I need the VoiceOver gestures to work in landscape exactly like they would work in portrait: left-right for navigation, up-down for adjustments. Currently because of the 90 degree rotation, left-right becomes adjustment instead of navigation, which is not what I want.

Comment: I just have tested camera app on iOS 10.0.1 and voiceover's swipe behaviour does not depend on device orientation, only parts of the UI rotate. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Did you try to add additional gesture recognisers for changed direction (so you will have right-left and up-down gestures) and enable/disable appropriate pair of gestures in case of screen rotation? The problem looks similar to different layout in case of different orientations when you use completely different root view (with duplicated hierarchy) for every orientation.